# Mapping unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a number in $\mathbb{R}$ is not one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

Let $C:=\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2:\lVert \vec{x} \rVert=1\}$. Show that a continuous function $f:C\to S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is not one-to-one.

> My approach:

Let $f(\vec{x})\in [a,b]$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $g(x)=x^2$. Then $g$ is continuous. $(g\circ f)(\vec{x})=[f(\vec{x})]^2\in [a^2, b^2]$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\forall z\in[a^2,b^2],\exists c\in [a,b]$ such that $g(c)=z\implies z = [f(\vec{x_0})]^2=c^2\implies \pm f(\vec{x_0})=c\implies \pm \vec{x}_0 \in f^{-1}(c)\cap C$.

Of course this proof is flawed. I'm not even utilizing the fact that $\vec{x_0}\in C$, so this can apply to any function... Would appreciate some help with this proof.

Comment: When you say $f(\vec{x})\in [a,b]$ you are hoping to say that the range of $f$ is all of $[a,b]$.  It should be $\subset$ instead of $\in$, you should say that $\vec {x}$ ranges over the circle and you need to justify that the image is a closed interval.  Then when you square $f$ you lose information.  Say $f$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$ and is one-to-one.  When you square it, $f*2$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ and is not one-to-one.

Comment: Your proof is not just flawed, it is incomprehensible. Where does $x_0$ all of a sudden come from? You appear $\pm$ to mean "plus or minus" first and "plus and minus" at the end (I think, again it is incomprehensible). And you appear to use something like $f(\pm x)=\pm f(x)$, which regardless of how exactly it is interpreted is simply not a given property of $f$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I'm re-reading my proof and your comment and really laughing.

Answer (score 1):

The result holds in more generality,called the [Borsuk-Ulam Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic argument. With $f$ being a continuous function from a compact connected set $C$ to $\Bbb R$, its image is a finite closed interval $[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a\leq b$. Since a constant function on $C$ is not injective, the interval is not reduced to a point: $a\neq b$. There are distinct points $x_a,x_b\in C$ with $f(x_a)=a$ and $f(x_b)=b$. The points $x_a,x_b$, like any pair of distinct points on $C$, delimit two different arcs of the circle (with only those two points as their intersection). The intermediate value theorem can be applied to each arc separately, producing for each a point$~x$ in the interior of the arc with $f(x)=\frac{a+b}2$. This gives two distinct points of $C$ with the same image under$~f$, proving that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why you're talking about a constant function.

Comment: I need two distinct points, so I need to show the interval is not just a single point, which would happen if $a=b$. A function whose image is a single point is constant, and of course $f$ cannot be constant. But I still need to say this for the argument to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is injective, and without loss of generality, assume $0 \in f(S^1)^\circ$. The set $A=S^1 \setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is connected, but $f(A)$ is not, hence $f$ is not continuous.

Another approach:

Let $x_0 = \min f(S^1), x_1 = \max f(S^1)$. Let $f(s_0) = x_0, f(s_1) = x_1$.

There are two paths (that are disjoint except for the start and end) joining $s_0, s_1$, call them $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$. Then
$f(\gamma_0((0,1))) = (x_0,x_1), f(\gamma_1((0,1))) = (x_0,x_1)$, hence
for any $x^* \in (x_0,x_1)$ there are points $t_0, t_1$ such that
$f(\gamma_0(t_0)) = x^* = f(\gamma_1(t_1))$. Since $\gamma_0(t_0) \neq \gamma_1(t_1)$ this contradicts injectivity.

Comment: Do you mean $0$ in the complement of $f(S_1)$?

Comment: No, $f(S^1)$ is a non empty interval if $f$ is continuous and injective, I want $0$ to be in the interior of the interval. (I am using the intermediate value theorem implicitly.)

Comment: How do you know that $A$ is connected and $f(A)$ is not? Looks like connectedness has not been covered yet in my class.

Comment: A circle with a single point removed is connected, it is straightforward to exhibit an explicit path joining any two remaining points.

Comment: How do you know $0$ is not an end point of of $f(S^1)$?

Comment: Because I picked a point in the interior.

Comment: Oh. I thought that was an asterisk without an explanation.

Comment: @copper.hat how do you know that $f(A)$ is not connected? Upd: I guess it's an interval missing one point. I don't know how your argument works nevertheless. I'd appreciate if you could please provide a detailed explanation how/why the entire process of your proof works, if possible.

Comment: The set $f(S^1)$ has $0$ in its interior, so $f(A) = [\min f(S^1),0) \cup (0, \max f(S^1)]$ which is disconnected. I added an alternative proof.